# mouse right click does nothing

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

A couple of days after a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 (no other OS) the right click functionality on my USB Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM) quit working on anything anywhere. Everything else works fine, but it is like it is like the right mouse button is completely disabled.

BTW, I've made sure the mouse is working on another system, No problems. Changed out the mouse with another that was verified to be working fine. No change. It's not the mouse!

The  xinput list | grep 'id=' line command returns:

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)    id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]

And the  xinput get-button-map 8  line command returns:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Anybody have any good ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "no change" in the second paragraph? Are you saying the other known good mouse also didn't work?

Comment: Yes. I tried two different units that are known to work on other systems and worked on this system, as well, prior to installing Ubuntu 12.04 and even for a couple of days after I installed Ubuntu 12.04. The point being that I'm 100% sure it is not a problem with this mouse or any other mouse. The problem is with some aspect of Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you try all of your usb ports?

Comment: Apparently gtweakui might fix it, change Desktop to "Use Nautilus to draw desktop"